# FUSE file system crashed at opening file (only in release mode)

Tags: c, fopen, fuse

I have some problem, and i can't find solution of this :/ I need to open a text file inside my fuse filesystem. In debug everything works fine, but in release system is crashing. I made a simples example, with this. Could anybody tell what's wrong in this code?

```
/*
  FUSE: Filesystem in Userspace
  Copyright (C) 2001-2007  Miklos Szeredi <miklos@szeredi.hu>

  This program can be distributed under the terms of the GNU GPL.
  See the file COPYING.

  gcc -Wall `pkg-config fuse --cflags --libs` hello.c -o hello
*/
#    define FUSE_USE_VERSION 26

#include  <fuse.h>
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <errno.h>
#include  <fcntl.h>

void stripnl(char *str) {
  while(strlen(str) && ( (str[strlen(str) - 1] == 13) || 
       ( str[strlen(str) - 1] == 10 ))) {
    str[strlen(str) - 1] = 0;
  }
}

static const char *hello_str = "Hello World!\n";
static const char *hello_path = "/hello";

static int hello_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf)
{
    int res = 0;
    memset(stbuf, 0, sizeof(struct stat));
    if (strcmp(path, "/") == 0) {
        stbuf->st_mode = S_IFDIR | 0755;
        stbuf->st_nlink = 2;
    } else if (strcmp(path, hello_path) == 0) {
        stbuf->st_mode = S_IFREG | 0444;
        stbuf->st_nlink = 1;
        stbuf->st_size = strlen(hello_str);
    } else
        res = -ENOENT;

    return res;
}

static int hello_readdir(const char *path, void *buf, fuse_fill_dir_t filler,
             off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    (void) offset;
    (void) fi;

    if (strcmp(path, "/") != 0)
        return -ENOENT;

    filler(buf, ".", NULL, 0);
    filler(buf, "..", NULL, 0);

    filler(buf, hello_path + 1, NULL, 0);

  FILE *infile;
  char fname[40];
  char line[100];
  int lcount;

      /* We need to get rid of the newline char. */
  stripnl(fname);

  /* Open the file.  If NULL is returned there was an error */
  if((infile = fopen("ex.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error Opening File.\n");
  }

  while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), infile) != NULL ) {
    /* Get each line from the infile */
    lcount++;
    /* print the line number and data */
    printf("Line %d: %s", lcount, line);  
    filler(buf, line, NULL, 0);
  }

  fclose(infile);  /* Close the file */

    return 0;
}

static int hello_open(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    if (strcmp(path, hello_path) != 0)
        return -ENOENT;

    if ((fi->flags & 3) != O_RDONLY)
        return -EACCES;

    return 0;
}

static int hello_read(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset,
              struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    size_t len;
    (void) fi;
    if(strcmp(path, hello_path) != 0)
        return -ENOENT;

    len = strlen(hello_str);
    if (offset < len) {
        if (offset + size > len)
            size = len - offset;
        memcpy(buf, hello_str + offset, size);
    } else
        size = 0;

    return size;
}

static struct fuse_operations hello_oper = {
    .getattr    = hello_getattr,
    .readdir    = hello_readdir,
    .open       = hello_open,
    .read       = hello_read,
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return fuse_main(argc, argv, &hello_oper, NULL);
}
```

**Update**

Ok, i've found solution, path must be absolute file path (not sure is this is proper sentence), but here is example code, which is working in release as well as in debug:

```
/*
  FUSE: Filesystem in Userspace
  Copyright (C) 2001-2007  Miklos Szeredi <miklos@szeredi.hu>

  This program can be distributed under the terms of the GNU GPL.
  See the file COPYING.

  gcc -Wall `pkg-config fuse --cflags --libs` hello.c -o hello
*/
#    define FUSE_USE_VERSION 26

#include  <fuse.h>
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <errno.h>
#include  <fcntl.h>

void stripnl(char *str) {
  while(strlen(str) && ( (str[strlen(str) - 1] == 13) || 
       ( str[strlen(str) - 1] == 10 ))) {
    str[strlen(str) - 1] = 0;
  }
}

static const char *hello_str = "Hello World!\n";
static const char *hello_path = "/hello";

static int hello_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf)
{
    int res = 0;
    memset(stbuf, 0, sizeof(struct stat));
    if (strcmp(path, "/") == 0) {
        stbuf->st_mode = S_IFDIR | 0755;
        stbuf->st_nlink = 2;
    } else if (strcmp(path, hello_path) == 0) {
        stbuf->st_mode = S_IFREG | 0444;
        stbuf->st_nlink = 1;
        stbuf->st_size = strlen(hello_str);
    } else
        res = -ENOENT;

    return res;
}

static int hello_readdir(const char *path, void *buf, fuse_fill_dir_t filler,
             off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    (void) offset;
    (void) fi;

    if (strcmp(path, "/") != 0)
        return -ENOENT;

    filler(buf, ".", NULL, 0);
    filler(buf, "..", NULL, 0);

    filler(buf, hello_path + 1, NULL, 0);

    FILE *infile;
    char line[100];

    if((infile = fopen("/root/Desktop/fexamples/ex.txt", "rb")) == NULL) 
    {
        return -1;
    }

    while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), infile) != NULL ) 
    {
            filler(buf, line, NULL, 0);
    }

    fclose(infile);  /* Close the file */

    return 0;
}

static int hello_open(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    if (strcmp(path, hello_path) != 0)
        return -ENOENT;

    if ((fi->flags & 3) != O_RDONLY)
        return -EACCES;

    return 0;
}

static int hello_read(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset,
              struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    size_t len;
    (void) fi;
    if(strcmp(path, hello_path) != 0)
        return -ENOENT;

    len = strlen(hello_str);
    if (offset < len) {
        if (offset + size > len)
            size = len - offset;
        memcpy(buf, hello_str + offset, size);
    } else
        size = 0;

    return size;
}

static struct fuse_operations hello_oper = {
    .getattr    = hello_getattr,
    .readdir    = hello_readdir,
    .open       = hello_open,
    .read       = hello_read,
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return fuse_main(argc, argv, &hello_oper, NULL);
}
```

Comment: next time save yourself some trouble and use the `{}` button in the editor to format your code.

Comment: Ok, sorry of that, next time i will do this.

Comment: could you be more specific about the crash? give a backtrace? pinoint the area where it's failing?

Comment: I have this error since Tuesday, now i restart VWware and attached example doesn't crash but don't read the file in release and read it in debug. Problem still occurs in my fs(here is simplest example), and application crash when i go into mount dir and execute ls. Then i get this: "ls: reading directory .: Software caused connection abort" - the same as before restart for attached example.

Comment: I check this with my log, and it's crashing while opening file.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues in your readdir implementation.

```
char fname[40];
char line[100];
int lcount;

/* We need to get rid of the newline char. */
stripnl(fname);
```

You're acting on the contents of fname that you're not initializing anywhere. This could do just about anything. The fact that you're not using `fname` after that is irrelevant, you could be modifying completely random data with that `stripnl` call.

```
/* Open the file.  If NULL is returned there was an error */
if((infile = fopen("ex.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error Opening File.\n");
}
```

If `fopen` fails, you should error out (or just leave) this function. Otherwise the next line will call `fgets` with `NULL` as its file argument.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've found solution, path must be absolute file path (not sure is this is proper sentence), but here is example code, which is working in release as well as in debug:

```
/*
  FUSE: Filesystem in Userspace
  Copyright (C) 2001-2007  Miklos Szeredi <miklos@szeredi.hu>

  This program can be distributed under the terms of the GNU GPL.
  See the file COPYING.

  gcc -Wall `pkg-config fuse --cflags --libs` hello.c -o hello
*/
#    define FUSE_USE_VERSION 26

#include  <fuse.h>
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <errno.h>
#include  <fcntl.h>

void stripnl(char *str) {
  while(strlen(str) && ( (str[strlen(str) - 1] == 13) || 
       ( str[strlen(str) - 1] == 10 ))) {
    str[strlen(str) - 1] = 0;
  }
}

static const char *hello_str = "Hello World!\n";
static const char *hello_path = "/hello";

static int hello_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf)
{
    int res = 0;
    memset(stbuf, 0, sizeof(struct stat));
    if (strcmp(path, "/") == 0) {
        stbuf->st_mode = S_IFDIR | 0755;
        stbuf->st_nlink = 2;
    } else if (strcmp(path, hello_path) == 0) {
        stbuf->st_mode = S_IFREG | 0444;
        stbuf->st_nlink = 1;
        stbuf->st_size = strlen(hello_str);
    } else
        res = -ENOENT;

    return res;
}

static int hello_readdir(const char *path, void *buf, fuse_fill_dir_t filler,
             off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    (void) offset;
    (void) fi;

    if (strcmp(path, "/") != 0)
        return -ENOENT;

    filler(buf, ".", NULL, 0);
    filler(buf, "..", NULL, 0);

    filler(buf, hello_path + 1, NULL, 0);

    FILE *infile;
    char line[100];

    if((infile = fopen("/root/Desktop/fexamples/ex.txt", "rb")) == NULL) 
    {
        return -1;
    }

    while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), infile) != NULL ) 
    {
            filler(buf, line, NULL, 0);
    }

    fclose(infile);  /* Close the file */

    return 0;
}

static int hello_open(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    if (strcmp(path, hello_path) != 0)
        return -ENOENT;

    if ((fi->flags & 3) != O_RDONLY)
        return -EACCES;

    return 0;
}

static int hello_read(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset,
              struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    size_t len;
    (void) fi;
    if(strcmp(path, hello_path) != 0)
        return -ENOENT;

    len = strlen(hello_str);
    if (offset < len) {
        if (offset + size > len)
            size = len - offset;
        memcpy(buf, hello_str + offset, size);
    } else
        size = 0;

    return size;
}

static struct fuse_operations hello_oper = {
    .getattr    = hello_getattr,
    .readdir    = hello_readdir,
    .open       = hello_open,
    .read       = hello_read,
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return fuse_main(argc, argv, &hello_oper, NULL);
}
```

Comment: If this is the solution, please mark it as such. Additionally, why are you posting the same huge code blob when a diff would be sufficient?